# How do I create a Java Swing JTable with header as first column, not as first row?

Tags: java, swing, header, jtable, transpose

I am using Java 6.0 + Swing + JTable.

Normally, JTable renders the header as the first row. (Left image)

However, I would like to render the header as the first column. (Right image)

I don't think this is a simple flag in JTable.

Can you please recommend an approach or existing widget library?

I assume I need to override the paint() methods for JTableHeader and JTable.

Thanks

[image: Table with header as first row]
[image: Table with header as first column]

Answer (score 1):

Oops, never mind you want a transposed TableModel, not just row headers.

See http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/18/row-number-table/

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using an TableModel, you should return an specific Class in getColumnClass, use a Renderer to paint its like an Header Column. And probably, you will going to make your getValueAt in vertical.

This is not simple, but is possible.

When I posted it the images your posted was not visible, to your case, you should use a CellRenderer to make it like a Header, but its still on TableModel.

Answer (score 0):

How about this, you basically override getValueAt(int row, int column). Here is a test class:

```
package so.pivot;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class Test extends JFrame{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Test test = new Test();
        String[] columnNames = {"First Name",
                "Last Name",
                "Sport",
                "# of Years",
                "Vegetarian"};
        Object[][] data = {
                {"Kathy", "Smith",
                 "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
                {"John", "Doe",
                 "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
                {"Sue", "Black",
                 "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
                {"Jane", "White",
                 "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
                {"Joe", "Brown",
                 "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)}
            };

        JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames){
            @Override
            public Object getValueAt(int row, int column){
                return super.getValueAt(column, row);
            }
        };

        test.add(table);
        test.pack();
        test.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I share the same issue. Here's my implementation. I have an array for headers which is fixed, and a 2d array for the rest of my data, which is populated via json although not relevant nor shown here. Do note this supports dynamic populating on a column level:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
    JTable table = new JTable(model);
    model.addColumn("Header");

    String[] headers = { //If you wish to separate the headers array from columns array
        "Header 1",
        "Header 2",
        "Header 3"
    };
    String [][]columnData = new String[][]{
        {
            "Column 1.1",
            "Column 1.2",
            "Column 1.3"
        },{
            "Column 2.1",
            "Column 2.2",
            "Column 2.3"
        },{
            "Column 3.1",
            "Column 3.2",
            "Column 3.3"
        }
    };

    for(int col=1;col<(columnData.length+1);col++){
        model.addColumn("Col"+col);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<headers.length;i++){
        model.addRow(new Object[] { headers[i] });
    }
    for(int r=0;r<columnData.length;r++){
        for(int c=0;c<columnData[0].length;c++){
            model.setValueAt(columnData[r][c],c,r+1);
        }
    }        
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setSize(500, 300);
    f.add(new JScrollPane(table));
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Here's the ouput:

[image: Populating by column (dynamically)]